# How to access DIO message of RPL on Contiki Cooja simulator?

Tags: c, simulator, contiki, cooja, contiki-process

Can somebody please help me with on how to access the DIO message from unicast-sender. C and unicast-receiver. The C file of RPL implementation of the Contiki cooja simulator??
We are working on sinkhole attack detection, that's why we need to analyze DIO message. As a beginner, we don't know how to access that from the code, but we can see it using packet analyzer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. You have to try it first and ask some issues.

Comment: We tried everything in our knowledge but those aren't even near working!It would have been helpful if someone helped with the solution!Thanks.